# Transforming date column from year-month-day to just year-month

Tags: r, date, datetime, ggplot2, data.table

I have a dataset with a date column. I am trying to take that date column and transform it to one that only has month and year, as a Posix date. The reason I need to be able to do this is to be able to use a bin that is a month wide in ggplot2 and scale_x_date. Here is a test dataset:

```
testset <- data.table(date=as.Date(c("2013-07-02","2013-08-03","2013-09-04","2013-10-05","2013-11-06","2013-07-03","2013-08-04","2013-09-05","2013-10-06","2013-11-07")), plant = LETTERS[1:5], PlantID = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,6,7), product = as.factor(letters[26:22]), rating = runif(30))
```

Basically, I want to turn the date column into one that is just year-month.

Any quick, eloquent ways to do such a thing?

EDIT: I created another thread that has more of the end goal of what I'm looking for. It is located here: [Creating month-sized bins with ggplot2 in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951875/creating-month-sized-bins-with-ggplot2-in-r)

Comment: `lubridate::floor_date(testset$date, "month")`

Comment: Base `R` would be: `as.Date(paste(format(testset$date,"%Y-%m"),"01",sep="-"))` which is fairly simple.

Comment: Or with `zoo` you could try `as.yearmon`. (`testset[, YM := as.yearmon(date)]`)

Comment: @hadley, that only shows the date as being the first of the month. I want to get rid of the day entry altogether. (%y %m)

Comment: You can't get rid of the day in a POSIX date. `as.yearmon` as suggested by @AnandaMahto will allow this though I think.

Comment: the zoo solution would have no day entry, but yearmon is not really a date.

Comment: @black_sheep07 (and @Ananda Mahto): ggplot doesn't understand 'yearmon' from the zoo package for date scales. If you want to use `scale_x_date` you *have* to use a Date or POSIX… class. You can make `as.yearmon` work, but you'll need to adapt your ggplot code accordingly.

Comment: @hrbrmstr how would I go about adapting for zoo? I've run across it a bit and I know that it does a lot with time series data, but I haven't had time to adapt it into my work particularly closely.

Comment: This might help get you going: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/zoo/docs/autoplot.zoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual:

"The "yearmon" class is used to represent monthly data. Internally it holds the data as year plus
0 for January, 1/12 for February, 2/12 for March and so on in order that its internal representa-
tion is the same as ts class with frequency = 12."

```
> require(zoo)
> as.yearmon("2007-03-01")
[1] "Mar 2007"
> as.numeric(as.yearmon("2007-03-01"))
[1] 2007.167
```

Is this what you really want, a yearmon which is a fraction of a year? If this works for you see

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/zoo.pdf