# Creating month-sized bins with ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, date, plot, ggplot2, data.table

I have a set of data that I need to plot in ggplot2. It is time ordered. This is the data set:

```
testset <- data.table(Date=as.Date(c("2013-07-02","2013-08-03","2013-09-04","2013-10-05","2013-11-06","2013-07-03","2013-08-04","2013-09-05","2013-10-06","2013-11-07")), Action = c("A","B","C","D","E","B","A","B","C","A","B","E","E","C","A"), rating = runif(30))
```

What I am doing is plotting it and using scale_x_date to put dated data on the graph. However, when I do this, it doesn't bin it into month-sized bins. Instead, it bins it by the day that the action was taken.

```
ggplot(testset, aes(Date, fill=Action)) + geom_bar(position="dodge") + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b %Y"), breaks = date_breaks(width = "months"))
```

What I would like to do is have all of the dates for each month placed into a single bin and then graphed. I haven't found any solutions when going through StackOverflow and nothing presented itself while going through the literature for ggplot2 or scale_x_date. I'm not opposed to using lubridate or zoo if they can provide the output that I am looking for.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: After seeing the answer below from @mnel, I ended up posting [a question about how to modify plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968702/modifying-plot-in-ggplot2-using-as-yearmon-from-zoo). Between the help that @tonytonov gave me there and that @mnel gave me here, I figured out a solution.

```
ggplot(testset, aes(as.factor(as.yearmon(Date)), fill=Action)) + 
geom_bar(position='dodge') + xlab("Date") + ylab("Count")
```

This ended up giving me this graph:

[image: final graph]

Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `yearmon` class from the `zoo` package. There is a `scale_..._yearmon` function in the `zoo` package that works similarly to the `scale_x_date` function in the `scales` package

```
library(zoo)
ggplot(testset, aes(as.yearmon(Date), fill=Action)) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width  = 1/12), 
           binwidth=1/12, colour='black') + 
  scale_x_yearmon()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to force the plot to drop the unused values for each month and automatically create the right sized bars? Because for every other plot that I create, that is the behavior and I'd like this to fit in.