# R aggregate by %Y-%b as date

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have a data frame `item_sold_time` with a `item_sold_time$SaleDate` "POSIXct" "POSIXt" column, looking like this `2015-04-28 07:59:43`.

I want to aggregate by *month in year*:

```
df2<-aggregate(list(Qty=item_sold_time$Qty), by=list(ISBN=item_sold_time$ISBN,DateYM=strftime(item_sold_time$SaleDate, format="%Y-%b")), FUN=sum)
```

The problem with `strftime` is that it converts the date into characters and I get an error if I try to convert it back into date.

I tried all combinations of date formatting, I could find in 2 days of searching. The final destination of that date is to be used in this plot:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x = DateYM, y=Qty))
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: date have year, month and day and not just year and month.

Comment: Ok, so no way to get it as date. But is there a way to aggregate by Year,Month only and still be able to order it as a date would be ordered (2013-jun before 2013-jul before 2014-mar)?

Comment: The package **zoo** has support for actual year-month columns, which can be useful.

Comment: Thank you @joran , I'll have look.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-yyyy-mm-format-to-a-date-in-r) is an example of using `zoo::as.yearmon()` to format month-year data as a date.  Then `scale_x_yearmon` should help with the plotting in [ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968702/modifying-plot-in-ggplot2-using-as-yearmon-from-zoo).

Answer (score 0):

Set each date to (e.g.) the 15th of the month, then can aggregate by date and plot as normal.

```
as.Date(format(item_sold_time$SaleDate, "%Y-%m-15"))
```

Comment: it does the job, but it's surprising that such basic operation needs such unintuitive solution