# Creating ggplot2 Histogram with Times Around Midnight

Tags: r, date, time, ggplot2, zoo

I have a set of data that is the end time of two industrial processes. These processes end around midnight every night and I am trying to visualize their performance next to each other by plotting a dodged histogram of the times that they end. Unfortunately, I don't know how to split the data in a way that `ggplot` will use it in a contiguous histogram. Here is a sample of the data that I am using:

```
testset <- data.table(ProcessA=as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 22:12:00",
                          "2015-01-02 22:53:00","2015-01-03 23:42:00",
                          "2015-01-05 00:02:00","2015-01-05 23:33:00",
                          "2015-01-06 23:56:00","2015-01-08 00:19:00",
                          "2015-01-08 23:29:00","2015-01-09 23:14:00",
                          "2015-01-11 00:01:00")), 
                       ProcessB=as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 22:12:00",
                          "2015-01-02 23:35:00","2015-01-03 23:18:00",
                          "2015-01-05 00:09:00","2015-01-05 23:03:00",
                          "2015-01-06 22:51:00","2015-01-08 00:22:00",
                          "2015-01-09 00:12:00","2015-01-09 23:01:00",
                          "2015-01-11 00:23:00")))
```

I have subsetted to get only the times by using:

```
testset$ProcessAtime <- substr(testset$ProcessA, 12, 16)
testset$ProcessAtime <- substr(testset$ProcessA, 12, 16)
```

However these give me things I can't plot and still stay around midnight. I've tried `zoo` but don't see a way to do what I'm asking to do. I have previously done things like this (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951875/creating-month-sized-bins-with-ggplot2-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968702/modifying-plot-in-ggplot2-using-as-yearmon-from-zoo)) but nothing that allows me to use times to create plots such as the one I would like to create.

Any help would be super greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you care about the date, or do you just want the time?

Comment: Only the time. I'd like a histogram of the times that it stopped.

Comment: >library(data.table) should be added as the first line of the sample data code. Also, did you mean to repeat testset$ProcessAtime <- substr(testset$ProcessA, 12, 16) twice, or should the second line refer to Process B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base R doesn't have a time only date format do you need a date. You can set them all to the same date, or if you want times near 0 to be near times near 24, you might split them across two dates. Here's an example of the latter

```
justtime <- function(x, split=12) {
    h <- as.numeric(strftime(x, "%H"))
    y <- as.POSIXct(paste(ifelse(h<split, "2015-01-02","2015-01-01"),strftime(x, "%H:%M:%S")))
}
```

Then you can plot with

```
ggplot(data.frame(time=justtime(testset$ProcessA)), aes(x=time)) + 
    geom_histogram()
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: I do not need a date. I need to not have one, in fact. I'll look through your solution. Thank you!

Comment: You can't not have a date if you want to work with time. You can create your own way of storing times, but then you'd have to do a lot of extra work to make ggplot understand it.

Comment: Gotcha. The only thing that I still need from this solution is having the histogram dodged. I need to view process A and process B side by side on the same plot.

Comment: Well, you seemed to have left that out of the original question. I'm pretty sure if you search a bit you'll find a different question specifically addressing that piece.